# lengths must match to compare (pandas selection on two criteria)

Tags: python, pandas

I am generating values per user like so:

```
loDf = locDfs[user] # locDfs is a copy of locationDf elsewhere in the code... sorry for all the variable names.
loDf.reset_index(inplace=True)
loDf = pd.crosstab([loDf.date, loDf.uid], loDf.location_id)
loDf.reset_index(inplace=True)

loDf.set_index('date', inplace=True)
loDf.drop('uid', axis=1, inplace=True)

# join the location crosstab columns with the app crosstab columns per user
userLocAppDfs[user] = userLocAppDfs[user].join(loDf, how='outer')
# convert from just "1" at each location change event followed by zeros, to "1" continuing until next location change
userLocAppDfs[user] = userLocAppDfs[user].resample('15T').agg('max')
userLocAppDfs[user]['uid'].fillna(user, inplace=True)
```

this takes the location data and converts the location_id's into columns, and combines it with other data in a timeseries.

That essentially covers reshaping the data. Then I need to normalize, and to do this, I need to look at each column value:

```
for loc in locationDf[(locationDf['location_id'] in loDf.columns.values) & (locationDf['uid'] == user)].location_id.unique():
```

Here's the complete function:

```
def normalize(inputMetricDf, inputLocationDf):
    '''
    normalize, resample, and combine data into a single data source
    '''
    metricDf = inputMetricDf.copy()
    locationDf = inputLocationDf.copy()

    appDf = metricDf[['date', 'uid', 'app_id', 'metric']].copy()

    locDf = locationDf[['date', 'uid', 'location_id']]
    locDf.set_index('date', inplace=True)

    # convert location data to "15 minute interval" rows
    locDfs = {}
    for user, user_loc_dc in locDf.groupby('uid'):
        locDfs[user] = user_loc_dc.resample('15T').agg('max').bfill()

    aDf = appDf.copy()
    aDf.set_index('date', inplace=True)

    userLocAppDfs = {}
    user = ''
    for uid, a2_df in aDf.groupby('uid'):
        user = uid
        # per user, convert app data to 15m interval
        userDf = a2_df.resample('15T').agg('max')

        # assign metric for each app to an app column for each app, per user
        userDf.reset_index(inplace=True)
        userDf = pd.crosstab(index=userDf['date'], columns=userDf['app_id'],
                             values=userDf['metric'], aggfunc=np.mean).fillna(np.nan, downcast='infer')

        userDf['uid'] = user

        userDf.reset_index(inplace=True)
        userDf.set_index('date', inplace=True)

        # reapply 15m intervals now that we have new data per app
        userLocAppDfs[user] = userDf.resample('15T').agg('max')

        # assign location data to location columns per location, creates a "1" at the 15m interval of the location change event in the location column created
        loDf = locDfs[user]
        loDf.reset_index(inplace=True)
        loDf = pd.crosstab([loDf.date, loDf.uid], loDf.location_id)
        loDf.reset_index(inplace=True)

        loDf.set_index('date', inplace=True)
        loDf.drop('uid', axis=1, inplace=True)

        # join the location crosstab columns with the app crosstab columns per user
        userLocAppDfs[user] = userLocAppDfs[user].join(loDf, how='outer')
        # convert from just "1" at each location change event followed by zeros, to "1" continuing until next location change
        userLocAppDfs[user] = userLocAppDfs[user].resample('15T').agg('max')
        userLocAppDfs[user]['uid'].fillna(user, inplace=True)

        for loc in locationDf[(locationDf['location_id'] in loDf.columns.values) & (locationDf['uid'] == user)].location_id.unique():
            # fill location NaNs
            userLocAppDfs[user][loc] = userLocAppDfs[user][loc].replace(
                np.nan, 0)

        # fill app NaNs
        for app in a2_df['app_id'].unique():
            userLocAppDfs[user][app].interpolate(
                method='linear', limit_area='inside', inplace=True)
            userLocAppDfs[user][app].fillna(value=0, inplace=True)

    df = userLocAppDfs[user].copy()

    # ensure actual normality
    alpha = 0.05
    for app in aDf['app_id'].unique():
        _, p = normaltest(userLocAppDfs[user][app])
        if(p > alpha):
            raise DataNotNormal(args=(user, app))

    # for loc in userLocAppDfs[user]:
        # could also test location data

    return df
```

but this produces the error:

```
  File "/env/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/google/cloud/functions/worker.py", line 346, in run_http_function
    result = _function_handler.invoke_user_function(flask.request)
  File "/env/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/google/cloud/functions/worker.py", line 223, in invoke_user_function
    loop.run_until_complete(future)
  File "/opt/python3.7/lib/python3.7/asyncio/base_events.py", line 573, in run_until_complete
    return future.result()
  File "/user_code/main.py", line 31, in default_model
    train, endog, exog, _, _, rawDf = preprocess(ledger, apps)
  File "/user_code/Wrangling.py", line 67, in preprocess
    rawDf = normalize(appDf, locDf)
  File "/user_code/Wrangling.py", line 185, in normalize
    for loc in locationDf[(locationDf['location_id'] in loDf.columns.values) & (locationDf['uid'] == user)].location_id.unique():
  File "/env/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pandas/core/ops.py", line 1745, in wrapper
    raise ValueError('Lengths must match to compare')
ValueError: Lengths must match to compare
```

Before I noticed that I could lose locations from the locationsDf because of reshaping, I was just doing:

```
    for loc in locationDf[locationDf['uid'] == user].location_id.unique():
```

and *this worked* for every other instance. but if you have two locations in the same 15t time segment and one of them only appears there, but is dropped because of the 15t window, then it gives me an error. So I need the other condition.

locationDf['location_id'] is just a string, just like the crosstab columnnames become.

Why is this throwing me an error?

#### errors with attempted answers:

```
    for loc in locationDf[(locationDf['location_id'].isin(loDf.columns.values)) & (locationDf['uid'].isin([user])), 'location_id'].unique():
  File "/env/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pandas/core/frame.py", line 2927, in __getitem__
    indexer = self.columns.get_loc(key)
  File "/env/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pandas/core/indexes/base.py", line 2657, in get_loc
    return self._engine.get_loc(key)
  File "pandas/_libs/index.pyx", line 108, in pandas._libs.index.IndexEngine.get_loc
  File "pandas/_libs/index.pyx", line 110, in pandas._libs.index.IndexEngine.get_loc
TypeError: '(0       True
1       True
2       True
3      False
4       True
5       True
6      False
7       True
8       True
9      False
10     False
11     False
12     False
13     False
14     False
15     False
16     False
17     False
18     False
19      True
20      True
21      True
22      True
23      True
24      True
25      True
26     False
27      True
28      True
29     False
       ...  
210    False
211    False
212    False
213    False
214    False
215    False
216    False
217    False
218     True
219     True
220    False
221    False
222    False
223    False
224    False
225    False
226     True
227    False
228     True
229    False
230    False
231     True
232    False
233     True
234    False
235    False
236    False
237     True
238    False
239    False
Length: 240, dtype: bool, 'location_id')' is an invalid key
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Change you condition to (using `isin`)

```
locationDf.loc[(locationDf['location_id'].isin(loDf.columns.values)) 
           & (locationDf['uid'].isin(user)),'location_id'].unique()
```

Update

```
con1 = (locationDf['location_id'].isin(loDf.columns.values)
con2 = (locationDf['uid'].isin(pd.Series(user))

locationDf.loc[con1&con2,'location_id'].unique()
```

Comment: Im pushing this to my app now, I imagine it will work.. but _why_ do they both have to be _isin_ when one of them is?

Comment: @robertotomás I am not sure `user` is `type list` or a string

Comment: its a list, I've enclosed it in brackets and pushing again

Comment: adding the rror I get to the bottom of the OP now

Comment: @robertotomás `locationDf.loc[(locationDf['location_id'].isin(loDf.columns.values.tolist())) & (locationDf['uid'].isin(user)),'location_id'].unique()` ummm would you like provide some sample data ?

Comment: @robertotomás so this is just a string ?`locationDf['location_id']`

Comment: yes, I did mention that -- thats all string data. (ps: applied the most recent revision, still gettiing the same true/false array error -- it doesn't like using isin selector with the 'locaton_id' in the same pair of brackets

Comment: @robertotomás also , if the user already is a list , you do not need `[user]` just do `user`

Comment: user is not already a list, it is just the current user under inspection. its good to see, at least, someone else is just as confused/delayed by the opaqueness of the pandas error responses as I am

Comment: So you need a extra protection here  `(locationDf['uid'].isin(pd.Series(user)))`@robertotomás

Comment: hmm, you didn't mean like this?:
`for locationDf.loc[(locationDf['location_id'].isin(loDf.columns.values.tolist())) & (locationDf['uid'].isin(pd.Series(user))), 'location_id'].unique():`
I am thinking that there's nothing wrong with the simple list form I used, but the `, 'location_id'` part is wrong

Comment: @robertotomás this is just .loc access the data , so locationDf do not have columns `location_id`?

Comment: locationDf is essentially the locDf at the top, that loDf is derrived from. I'll revise my OP to contain the complete function

Comment: `        for loc in locationDf[(locationDf['location_id'].isin(loDf.columns.values)) & (locationDf['uid'].isin([user]))].location_id.unique():
` works :) thanks

Comment: @robertotomás AHA we made it